# Error while trying to install mmengine (ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'pkg_resources.extern')

Tags: python

Error found with Python 3.8 and pip 20.0.2.

Following mmsegmentation install instructions, when running the command

```
mim install mmengine
```

I was getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 602, in _exec
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'pkg_resources.extern' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mim", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mim/commands/install.py", line 72, in cli
    exit_code = install(list(args), index_url=index_url, is_yes=is_yes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mim/commands/install.py", line 108, in install
    importlib.reload(pip._vendor.pkg_resources)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 169, in reload
    _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 608, in _exec
KeyError: 'pkg_resources'
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to downgrade pip

```
python -m pip install pip~=19.0
```

After downgrading pip, everything works fine.